# User can't see database in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I took a backup of a SQL Server database and restored it as a new database on a different server.

On this new instance I have done the following:

- recreated the login,
- associated the login with the db user using `sp_change_users_login 'UPDATE_ONE', 'username', 'username'`
- ensured the users default schema was `dbo`.
- ensured the users was a member of the `db_readdata` role.
- checked to make sure the user showed up in `sys.dabase_principals`
- granted the user View Definition
- granted connect to the user.

When I log in as the user I still do not see the database.  They can see other databases but not this one.

What else is there to check?

I ran `EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Report'` and this shows no output however running autofix, or `update_one` appear to run successfully.  The user also shows up under `security>Users`.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through the sames steps as you described.  Restoring a database from one server to another and then fixing the user.  I didn't give any additonal permissions though, as you did with GRANT VIEW DEFINITION.

If however, I execute `DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE to PUBLIC` on Instance B, myuser can no longer see `mydatabase` in SSMS, but he can connect to mydatabase and run queries either way.

Without `DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE` , myuser on Instance B, was able to see the restored database.  I then used the opposite statement `GRANT VIEW ANY DATABASE TO public` to give that permission back.

Is there anything here in this test that you did that I didn't?

Is the user on the server with the restored database still able to connect to that database and run queries?

**On Instance A**

-- Create the mydatabase database

```
CREATE DATABASE mydatabase 
CREATE TABLE mytable(t INT)
INSERT INTO mytable (t) VALUES (1),(2)
```

> create the login myuser, with default schema dbo and is member of 
>   db_datareader.

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [myuser] WITH PASSWORD=N'test123', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[mydatabase], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
USE [mydatabase]
GO
CREATE USER [myuser] FOR LOGIN [myuser]
GO
USE [mydatabase]
GO
ALTER USER [myuser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
USE [mydatabase]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'myuser'
GO
```

-- Backup the database

```
BACKUP DATABASE mydatabase to disk = 'C:\MSSQL\Backup\mydatabase.bak'
GO
```

**On Instance B**

-- restore the database to instance B

```
RESTORE DATABASE mydatabase FROM DISK = 'C:\MSSQL\BACKUP\mydatabase.bak'
WITH FILE=1,
MOVE 'mydatabase' TO 'C:\MSSQL\mydatabase.mdf',
MOVE 'mydatabase_log' TO 'C:\MSSQL\mydatabase_log.mdf',
RECOVERY, NOUNLOAD, STATS=10
```

-- recreate the login,

```
CREATE LOGIN [myuser] WITH PASSWORD=N'test123', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[mydatabase], CHECK_POLICY=OFF, CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF
```

-- fix the user

```
USE [mydatabase]
sp_change_users_login 'UPDATE_ONE', 'myuser', 'myuser'
```

-- connect to instance B in SSMS as myuser

```
use mydatabase
select * from mytable

t
1
2
```

**Connect as myuser to InstanceB using mydatabase**

[image]

**Show all databases connected as myuser to InstanceB**

[image]

I found this on answer on stackoverflow which provides a query that returns users and their permissions for a given database:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048839/sql-server-query-to-find-all-permissions-access-for-all-users-in-a-database